# Unable to connect to webserice from IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I am trying to access a web service which is hosted by a third party service.
I am able to browse through the web service URL. The issue right now is am
not able to connect to the webserivce when I try access from IIS(5.1).
From the visual studio web server I am able to connect and get the results
When I try from IIS am getting the following error
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "

Thanks,
Nithin

Comment: may be that you have network problem? try to ping the external service from the IIS server ...

Comment: Could you please explain how to ping from IIS? Am able to access the Web service URL.

Comment: Open a cmd console on the IIS server machine and type:
ping -a www.yourwebservicehost.com
where www.yourwebservicehost.com is the url of the webservices